# Does wave / subgroup need synchronization for shared variables?

Tags: opengl, glsl, vulkan

I am wondering if within a same wave / subgroup (warp?) we need to call `memoryBarrierShared` and `barrier` to synchronize shared variable? In NVIDIA I think it is not necessary, but I do not know for other IHVs.

EDIT : ballot

Since I am talking about wave / subgroup, I am talking about the `ARB_shader_ballot` extension.

Let's say we have such code (1) :

```
shared uint s_data[128];
uint tid = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
// initialization of some s_data
memoryBarrierShared();
barrier();
if(tid < gl_SubGroupSizeARB) {
    for(uint i = gl_SubGroupeSizeARB; i > 0; i>>=1)
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid + i];
}
```

According to me, this code is not correct. The correct one, according to the spec, would be (2):

```
if(tid < gl_SubGroupSizeARB) {
    for(uint i = gl_SubGroupeSizeARB; i > 0; i>>=1) {
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid + i];
        memoryBarrierShared();
        barrier();
    }
}
```

However, since invocations run in parallel within a wave/subgroup, the `barrier` function seems to be useless : this one should be correct as well and faster than the second (3) :

```
if(tid < gl_SubGroupSizeARB) {
    for(uint i = gl_SubGroupeSizeARB; i > 0; i>>=1) {
        s_data[tid] += s_data[tid + i];
        memoryBarrierShared();
    }
}
```

However, since we do not need `barrier` function, I wonder if (1) is correct, even if it is unlikely for me, and if not, if (3) is correct (that would means that my understanding is correct)

EDIT : int to uint, and change `=` to `+=`

Comment: "*According to me, this code is not correct.*" Well, what exactly is it supposed to do? I don't understand what your code is intended to accomplish. I have no idea what `s_data` is, what values it has, or what it is intended to eventually store. And since all versions of your code exhibit UB, it's not clear what is supposed to be happening here.

Comment: The idea of my code is to accomplish a reduction. (I wanted to write `+=` instead of `=`). `s_data` is only "values". What UB do my codes have?

Comment: In *every* case, you have invocations reading from memory that some other invocation will write to with no barriers between them to provide ordering/visibility. Even in your case 2, an invocation where `tid == 1` will write to a variable that the `tid == 0` invocation reads from. That's undefined behavior, whether `shader_ballot` exists or not.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier What are you hoping to accomplish?  I'm not sure you understand what warp level primitives are. Why are you using shared memory?  You can just access registers between warps and add those values (though in glsl you'll need the extension to accomplish this).  This has nothing to do with ARB_shader_ballot, which defines `uint64_t ballotARB(bool value);` which given a bool variable, checks across warp what the value will be accross warp and returns a bit field of evaluated bool.

Comment: @opa the `ARB_SHADER_BALLOT` defines the `gl_SubGroupSizeARB`. Globally, I want to understand if the code proposed by http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2010/presentations/S12312-DirectCompute-Pre-Conference-Tutorial.pdf (reduction #5 Unroll the last warp) is correct for each IHVs or only for NVIDIA?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier ARB_shader_ballot must define a groupsize, but that is not it's purpose.  shader_ballot makes no guarantees about the underlying architecture beyond the fact that ballotARB works if the vendor has implemented the extension.  Unrolling the last warp works because all other warps are free to do other work with in a Streaming Multiprocessor (NV specific) but also relies on undefined behavior **EVEN ON NVIDIA GPUS** to carry out adding values simultaneously accumulated from each warp.  (cont.)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier This is an extremely old article, nearing on a decade, and Nvidia hardware has changed and Nvidia has since updated its best practices with respect to using warp level primitives in CUDA, syncing warps is now recommended with using inter warp memory conflict operations https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives/.  On nvidia gpus with cuda, this is accomplished with `__syncwarp()`.  I would not expect this to be at all defined on other GPUs, and I would even go as far to expect this to break on both other vendors GPUS like AMD and newer Nvidia GPUs like Turing.

Comment: @AntoineMorrier If you look at turing architecture, they have removed half the floating point units per warp, and replaced half with integer units, and reduced the load store units to a fourth of what they were.  It may even be impossible for threads in a warp to complete such memory operations at the same time now given these restrictions, and even if they still worked on Nvidia gpus, that would only be because the load store units are spitting out all data at once to a contiguous piece of memory, register values would not be updated simultaneously per thread in warp.

Comment: @opa Okay, so what you point out is even on nvidia, the code given by the article is dangerous and has an UB?

Comment: @opa I am not english fluent, but we agree that when you said `I would not expect this to be at all defined on other GPUs, and I would even go as far to expect this to break on both other vendors GPUS like AMD and newer Nvidia GPUs like Turing`, you were not talking about __syncwarp but you were talking about the code given by the article?

Comment: @AntoineMorrier 1) Yes, the code is UB on Nvidia GPUs.  2) Yes, I was talking about the code in the article.  There either should be a `__syncwarp` extension provided for GLSL, or it should be built into other primitives provided by extension, for example  `ballotARB` internally may just be the `__ballot_sync` cuda function on Nvidia gpus, which performs ballot and syncs the warp ensuring safe result.

Comment: Why gp gpu is so complicate ahaha ^^. Thanks for your answers to both of you :)

Answer (score 3):

The execution model shared by OpenGL and Vulkan with regard to compute shaders does not really recognize the concept of a "wave". It has the concept of a work group, but that is not the same thing. A work group can be much bigger than a GPU "wave", and for small work groups, multiple work groups could be executing on the same GPU "wave".

As such, these specifications make no statements about the behavior of any of its functions with regard to a "wave" (with the exception of shader ballot functions). So if you want synchronization that the standard says will work on all conforming implementations, you must call both functions as dictated by the standard.

Even with `ARB_shader_ballot`, its behavior does not modify the *execution model* of shaders. It only allows cross-communication between subgroups, and *only* via the explicit mechanisms that it provides.

The execution model and memory model of shader invocations is that they are unordered with respect to each other, unless you explicitly order them with barriers.

Comment: I am talking about the shader ballot functions :). I am talking about it because I want to optimize my code by using this extension :)

Comment: @AntoineMorrier: No, you aren't. You mentioned shared variables, `barrier` and `memoryBarrierShared`. Nowhere did you bring up shader ballot stuff. So you should fix your question to ask about what you wanted to know about, preferably with some source code.